# Start Tmux with Command & Specify Configuration File

Tags: command, tmux

I'm working on small script that is interactive.  I'm trying to start tmux both specifying the command (so that when the process exits the tmux session exits) and using a configuration file - but it doesn't appear that this is possible.

```
tmux new-session -d -s myapp 'python myapp.py' -f 'myapp-tmux.conf'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another option may be to write a shell script that executes various commands currently in `myapp-tmux.conf` before the `tmux new-session ...`, rather than have `tmux` use a different `.conf` file. How (and if) you would do this depends on what `myapp-tmux.conf` does.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to move the `-f …` to before `new-session`. It is an argument for *tmux* itself; the `new-session` (sub)command does not understand or accept `-f`.

Also, the configuration file (`~/.tmux.conf`, or the one specified with `-f`) is only used when initially starting a server. If you have other (possibly detached) sessions running under the default server, then the `-f …` portion of your command will go unused. Check for other sessions with `tmux ls`.

---

You might want to use `-L` (or `-S`) to specify an alternate server (i.e. one where you can make sure your session is always the only one):

```
tmux -L myapp -f myapp-tmux.conf new-session -d -s myapp 'python myapp.py'
```

Later, to attach to that session:

```
tmux -L myapp attach -t myapp
```

(You may leave off `-t myapp` if the sever only has that one session.)

---

If you do want to use you existing server (so that changes made via the configuration file can affect your other sessions), then you might want to use `source` instead:

```
tmux source myapp-tmux.conf \; new-session -d -s myapp 'python myapp.py'
```